# kubernetes nodeport external ip not accessible

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I have been trying to deploy the **Spring Boot** application on **kubernetes** cluseter. But somehow I can not access the rest end point from outside the cluster.

Here are the steps which i performed

1. Setup the kubernetes cluster using kubespray following the guide - [Kubernetes Cluster setup using Kubespray](https://jhooq.com/kubespray-12-steps-for-installing-a-production-ready-kubernetes-cluster/)
2. Pushed the spring boot docker image to docker hub
3. Created kubernetes deployment

```
vagrant@node1:~/spring-boot$ kubectl create deployment demo --image=rahulwagh17/kubernetes:jhooq-k8s-springboot
```

```
deployment.apps/demo created
```

4. Exposed the deployment with external IP = 1.1.1.1

```
kubectl expose deployment demo --type=LoadBalancer --name=demo-service --external-ip=1.1.1.1 --port=8080

service/demo-service exposed
```

5. This is how my deployment is looking

```
vagrant@node1:~/spring-boot$ kubectl get deployment
NAME   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
demo   1/1     1            1           24s
```

6. This is how my services are looking

```
vagrant@node1:~/spring-boot$ kubectl get service
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
demo-service   LoadBalancer   10.233.31.159   1.1.1.1       8080:30099/TCP   13s
kubernetes     ClusterIP      10.233.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          23h
```

8. I can curl the rest end point within the cluster without a problem

```
vagrant@node1:~/spring-boot$ curl 10.233.31.159:8080/hello
Hello - Jhooq-k8s
```

**Problem I am facing - When i am trying to curl the rest point from outside the cluster, i can not do**

```
$ curl http://1.1.1.1:30099/hello
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 1.1.1.1 port 30099: Operation timed out
```

I am little new to kubernetes, so any leads or suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: When you say outside the cluster? What exactly you mean? From the host machine or what?

Comment: You do are covering that `1.1.1.1` right? And you do have the firewall rules allowing 30099?

Comment: Outside the cluster - I mean when i am trying to access it from my laptop browser. (I setup the kubernetes cluster on my laptop, so everything which i am doing, i am doing on my laptop. So exposing the service from kubernetes cluster, i am expecting it to be accessible from laptop )

Comment: @suren - I have disabled the firewall already - vagrant@node1:~/spring-boot$ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup

Comment: Is that `1.1.1.1` IP address something you control?  Is there a proxy server running there listening to port 30099 that can forward to your cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Please try via below approach:
 **Via Node Port**:- Which means `NodeIP:NodePort` and in this case, please get any node-ip and then run a command

```
curl http://$NODE_IP:30099/hello
```

and you should be able to access your service.

Comment: Curling - http://1.1.1.1:8080 or accessing the http://1.1.1.1:8080 from browser doesn't work

Comment: The `type=LoadBalancer` service is backed by external cloud providers

Comment: Try via `NodePort`

Comment: Yeah tried with the NodePort already but didn't get any success

kubectl expose deployment demo --type=NodePort --name=demo-service --external-ip=1.1.1.1 --port=8080


vagrant@node1:~/spring-boot$ kubectl get service
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
demo-service   NodePort    10.233.39.41   1.1.1.1       8080:31901/TCP   4s

Comment: Now, using this you have to hit `http:$VAGRANTIP:31901`

Comment: Great it worked using the vagrant ip - $ curl http://100.0.0.2:31901/hello
Hello - Jhooq-k8s

But now i am confused - When i am assigning the EXTERNAL-IP .i.e. 1.1.1.1 then it should be accessible on curl http://1.1.1.1:31901/hello ?

Comment: I would suggest you to follow this article, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/ as External-IP is usually on Cloud or Set your own LB in front of Kuberentes Cluster

Comment: I hope this answers your question as you should be able to access it outside the cluster. There are always few things which you can't do easily on your local laptop. Let's close this question